# Python: checking file and outputting to a new file

Tags: python, file, if-statement, for-loop

I have an sample filename file:

```
chr7    149601  MERGED_DEL_2_39754  T   .   141.35  .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;DP=37;MQ=37.00;MQ0=0;1000gALT=<DEL>;AF1000g=0.09;AFR_AF=0.01;AMR_AF=0.03;ASN_AF=0.27;EUR_AF=0.04;TS=HPGOM;TSseq=T,T,G,T,T;CAnc=T;GAnc=T;OAnc=T;mSC=0.000;GRP=-2.16;Map20=1    GT:DP:GQ:PL:A:C:G:T:IR  0/0:37:99:0,111,1458:0,0:0,0:0,0:18,18:0
chr7    149616  rs190051229 C   .   108.65  .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;DP=35;MQ=37.00;MQ0=0;1000gALT=T;AF1000g=0.00;ASN_AF=0.01;CpG;TS=HPGOM;TSseq=C,C,C,C,C;CAnc=C;GAnc=C;OAnc=C;mSC=0.000;GRP=-2.15;Map20=1    GT:DP:GQ:PL:A:C:G:T:IR  0/0:35:78.65:0,79,1305:0,0:17,17:0,0:0,0:0
chr7    149628  rs3814456   A   .   129.31  .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;DP=37;MQ=37.00;MQ0=0;1000gALT=G;AF1000g=0.14;AFR_AF=0.16;AMR_AF=0.07;ASN_AF=0.27;EUR_AF=0.06;TS=HPGOM;TSseq=A,A,A,A,A;CAnc=A;GAnc=A;OAnc=A;mSC=0.000;GRP=-2.23;Map20=1    GT:DP:GQ:PL:A:C:G:T:IR  0/0:37:99:0,99,1290:14,22:0,0:0,0:0,0:0
chr7    149634  rs146001818 G   T   1375.63 .   AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=0.456;DP=39;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HRun=0;HaplotypeScore=0.9997;MQ=37.00;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=1.641;QD=35.27;ReadPosRankSum=1.459;1000gALT=T;AF1000g=0.01;AFR_AF=0.01;AMR_AF=0.01;EUR_AF=0.03;TS=HPGOM;TSseq=G,G,G,G,G;CAnc=G;GAnc=G;OAnc=G;mSC=0.001;GRP=0.0686;Map20=1;ANN=T|upstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|LOC100507642|LOC100507642|transcript|NR_108064.1|Noncoding||n.-1G>T|||||84|,T|upstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|LOC100507642|LOC100507642|transcript|NR_108065.1|Noncoding||n.-1G>T|||||84|,T|intergenic_region|MODIFIER|LOC100507642|LOC100507642|intergenic_region|LOC100507642||||||||| GT:DP:GQ:PL:A:C:G:T:IR  1/1:39:74.36:1409,74,0:0,0:0,0:0,1:15,22:0
chr7    149645  rs112562180 C   .   165.42  .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;DP=46;MQ=37.00;MQ0=0;1000gALT=A;AF1000g=0.02;AFR_AF=0.03;AMR_AF=0.03;EUR_AF=0.02;TS=HPGOM;TSseq=C,C,C,C,C;CAnc=C;GAnc=C;OAnc=C;mSC=0.000;GRP=-1.93;Map20=1    GT:DP:GQ:PL:A:C:G:T:IR  0/0:46:99:0,135,1758:0,0:22,22:0,0:1,0:0
chr7    149659  rs79606188  T   .   195.53  .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;DP=55;MQ=37.00;MQ0=0;1000gALT=A;AF1000g=0.02;AFR_AF=0.07;AMR_AF=0.01;TS=HPGOM;TSseq=T,T,T,T,G;CAnc=T;GAnc=T;OAnc=T;mSC=0.005;GRP=0.0203;Map20=1   GT:DP:GQ:PL:A:C:G:T:IR  0/0:55:99:0,166,2189:0,0:0,0:0,0:26,28:0
chr7    149724  rs193238495 C   .   216.56  .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;DP=62;MQ=37.18;MQ0=0;1000gALT=T;AF1000g=0.00;AFR_AF=0.01;CpG;TS=HPGOM;TSseq=C,C,C,C,C;CAnc=C;GAnc=C;OAnc=C;mSC=0.000;GRP=-0.139;Map20=1   GT:DP:GQ:PL:A:C:G:T:IR  0/0:62:99:0,187,2385:0,0:37,24:0,0:0,0:0
chr7    149765  rs3814455   C   .   198.52  .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;DP=56;MQ=37.73;MQ0=0;1000gALT=T;AF1000g=0.54;AFR_AF=0.35;AMR_AF=0.60;ASN_AF=0.31;EUR_AF=0.79;TS=HPGOM;TSseq=C,C,C,C,C;CAnc=C;GAnc=C;OAnc=C;mSC=0.000;GRP=-0.494;Map20=1   GT:DP:GQ:PL:A:C:G:T:IR  0/0:56:99:0,169,2174:0,0:22,32:0,0:0,0:0
chr7    149785  rs185668085 C   .   192.52  .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;DP=54;MQ=37.76;MQ0=0;1000gALT=G;AF1000g=0.01;ASN_AF=0.04;TS=HPGOM;TSseq=C,C,C,C,C;CAnc=C;GAnc=C;OAnc=C;mSC=0.002;GRP=-0.216;Map20=1   GT:DP:GQ:PL:A:C:G:T:IR  0/0:54:99:0,163,2135:0,0:19,33:0,0:0,0:0
chr7    149825  rs189449059 C   .   156.38  .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;DP=42;MQ=37.71;MQ0=0;1000gALT=T;AF1000g=0.00;TS=HPGOM;TSseq=C,C,C,C,-;CAnc=C;GAnc=C;OAnc=C;mSC=0.000;GRP=0.693;Map20=1    GT:DP:GQ:PL:A:C:G:T:IR  0/0:42:99:0,126,1609:0,0:17,24:0,0:0,0:0
chr7    149863  .   G   A   407.49  .   AC=1;AF=0.50;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-1.315;DP=37;Dels=0.00;FS=1.341;HRun=1;HaplotypeScore=1.9995;MQ=37.00;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=-0.201;QD=11.01;ReadPosRankSum=1.469;TS=HPGOM;TSseq=G,G,G,G,G;CAnc=G;GAnc=G;OAnc=G;mSC=0.000;GRP=-1.5;Map20=1;ANN=A|non_coding_exon_variant|MODIFIER|LOC100507642|LOC100507642|transcript|NR_108064.1|Noncoding|1/3|n.146G>A||||||,A|non_coding_exon_variant|MODIFIER|LOC100507642|LOC100507642|transcript|NR_108065.1|Noncoding|1/2|n.146G>A||||||    GT:DP:GQ:PL:A:C:G:T:IR  0/1:37:99:437,0,759:6,8:0,0:13,9:0,0:0
chr7    149880  rs115127983 C   .   108.24  .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;DP=26;MQ=37.00;MQ0=0;1000gALT=G;AF1000g=0.04;AFR_AF=0.15;AMR_AF=0.02;CpG;TS=HPGOM;TSseq=C,C,C,C,C;CAnc=C;GAnc=C;OAnc=C;mSC=0.003;GRP=-1.24;Map20=1    GT:DP:GQ:PL:A:C:G:T:IR  0/0:26:78.25:0,78,1029:0,0:15,10:0,0:0,0:0
chr7    150067  rs181041230 G   .   138.34  .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;DP=36;MQ=38.37;MQ0=0;1000gALT=A;AF1000g=0.00;AFR_AF=0.01;TS=HPGOM;TSseq=G,G,G,G,G;CAnc=G;GAnc=G;OAnc=G;mSC=0.005;GRP=0.119;Map20=1    GT:DP:GQ:PL:A:C:G:T:IR  0/0:36:99:0,108,1425:0,0:0,0:16,19:0,0:0
chr7    150253  rs28397846  A   .   159.4   .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;DP=43;MQ=39.05;MQ0=0;1000gALT=G;AF1000g=0.03;AFR_AF=0.14;AMR_AF=0.02;TS=HPGOM;TSseq=A,A,A,-,G;CAnc=A;GAnc=A;OAnc=A;mSC=0.000;GRP=-2.18;Map20=1    GT:DP:GQ:PL:A:C:G:T:IR  0/0:43:99:0,129,1687:24,19:0,0:0,0:0,0:0
chr7    150280  rs139905037 A   .   159.4   .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;DP=45;MQ=38.96;MQ0=0;1000gALT=G;AF1000g=0.00;ASN_AF=0.01;TS=HPGOM;TSseq=A,A,A,-,-;CAnc=A;GAnc=A;OAnc=A;mSC=0.000;GRP=-0.168;Map20=1   GT:DP:GQ:PL:A:C:G:T:IR  0/0:45:99:0,129,1682:19,25:0,1:0,0:0,0:0
chr7    150353  rs75914010  A   .   162.42  .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;DP=45;MQ=37.00;MQ0=0;1000gALT=T;AF1000g=0.02;AFR_AF=0.03;AMR_AF=0.02;EUR_AF=0.02;TS=HPGOM;TSseq=A,A,A,A,A;CAnc=A;GAnc=A;OAnc=A;mSC=0.000;GRP=-0.647;Map20=1   GT:DP:GQ:PL:A:C:G:T:IR  0/0:45:99:0,132,1739:21,24:0,0:0,0:0,0:0
chr7    150356  rs185358707 C   .   113.39  .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;DP=43;MQ=37.00;MQ0=0;1000gALT=T;AF1000g=0.00;CpG;TS=HPGOM;TSseq=C,C,C,C,C;CAnc=C;GAnc=C;OAnc=C;mSC=0.000;GRP=-1.59;Map20=1    GT:DP:GQ:PL:A:C:G:T:IR  0/0:43:83.39:0,83,1538:0,1:19,21:0,0:2,0:0
```

My goal is to save all lines that are within a specified range. 
This is what I have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

file=open('filename')
sys.stdout=open('mega1.txt', 'w')

for line in file:
    fields = line.strip().split()
    chrm = fields[0]
    pos = int(fields[1])
    id1    = fields[2]
    if id1 in range(149601, 1149601):
        print line
```

I am not sure why it continues to run.

For this samplefile name, all the lines will be saved into the new mega1.txt file as the values in column2 all fit the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be checking wrong data in if.

You are checking `id1` which is `str` with `range(149601, 1149601)`.

You have to check `pos` with this range.

Please try this it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

fp=open('filename')
sys.stdout = open('mega1.txt', 'w')

for line in fp:
    fields = line.strip().split()
    chrm = fields[0]
    pos = int(fields[1])
    id1    = fields[2]
    if pos in range(149601, 1149601):
        print line
```

Comment: How did I miss that?! Thanks so much. careless mistake I made

Comment: If you got your answer, you can select this as answer, so other face same issue, then get answer too.